# Aperte Reports Multiple Filters with Single Filtered Select

Tags: java, jasper-reports, liferay-6

I want to use input type "filtered_select" and "filter" in a way that on selecting value from one select box two more select box should filter values.

If I have some data in organization table and two more tables employees and projects. I want to select One organization. Depending upon my selection other two drop downs should fetch all employees and projects of that organization.

Answer (score 0):

You need to achieve this by using AJAX calls. On click, you need to fire the query to database and populate data in respective drop down employees and projects. You would need to use `serveResource()` method.

Comment: I am using the aperte reports plugin for liferay for displaying reports and I am using it's core components. What I want is a sample report that can achieve this functionality. I have not changed the aperte source code. Can you please help ?